# Save image to ImgBox with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, image, post

I would like to save an image uploaded by my users to [IMGBox](https://imgbox.com/) with Javascript, I don't have a server and this is a static site.

Something like this

```
<form action="https://imgbox.com/uploadapi" method="POST">
    <label class="form-label">Image</label><br>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cadeImage">
 <button type="submit" class="button button-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I just have to upload the images to someplace online. IMGBox is only what I know, any alternative will do.

Comment: Maybe try this https://github.com/empun/imgbox-js

Comment: @DevQuayle But how? I am not familiar with the modules.